# React Router how to return 404 page in case of dynamic routes expecting a parameter?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Say I have the following route defined in a Switch:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/:pageId' component={Template} />
<Switch>
```

In the template I pass :pageId to the API and it returns the content for that page. It all works well, however the app crashes if I pass a :pageId value that does no exists (like I have no page with a slug "contact").

How can I make it redirect to a 404 page in this case so as to avoid the app crashing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your app won't know if a pageId value exists or not until it hits that route and queries your API. In cases like these I find that it's best to simply render "page not found" somewhere within the Template component after the server comes back with nothing.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's what I will have to do, put a condition on the template component to load the content returned by the API or redirect to the 404 page if it comes back null/undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're just passing a variable page id to the Route component and not specifically naming each route, you'll want to have the Template component return a 404 page in the case where the server returns nothing.

Switch will take a fall-through component in the case where none of the available paths match the given path, but that only works in case where you're using specific, named paths, ie `/users`, not with one route linking to variable page names.

Comment: Normally this would definitely work for a 404 page but in this case a conditional route makes anything valid for example "/thisPageDoesNotExist" would still be a valid path for the first route and "thisPageDoesNotExist" would be passed as the pageId in Params.

Comment: Oh, damn. You're completely right, good catch. The right solution is to render the "page not found" in the Template component, then.

Comment: Right on. If you update your answer I'll upvote your post :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yeah the app will crash if you pass any value that returns null/undefined from the api as the param. I think the suggestion of rendering the "page not found" in the template component is the way to go. I think using a redirect there could also work.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to utilize React 16 error boundaries. Then you can simply throw whenever (as long as it is inside a render method IIRC) you know the route is invalid.

```
class RouteNotFoundError extends Error {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args)
        // extending Error is fickle in a transpiler world - use name check instead of instanceof/constructor
        this.name = "RouteNotFoundError"
    }
}

const RouteNotFoundBoundary = withRouter(
    class RouteNotFoundBoundary extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = { routeNotFound: undefined }
        }
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            if (this.props.location !== nextProps.location) {
                this.setState({routeNotFound: false})
            }
        }
        componentDidCatch(e) {
            if (e.name === "RouteNotFoundError") {
                this.setState({routeNotFound: this.props.location.key})
            } else {
                throw e
            }
        }
        render() {
            if (this.state.routeNotFound === this.props.location.key) {
                return this.props.fallback || <div>Not found!</div>
            } else {
                return this.props.children
            }
        }
    }
)

const Template = props => {
    if (!allMyPages[props.match.params.pageId]) {
        throw new RouteNotFoundError()
    }

    return renderMyPage(allMyPages[props.match.params.pageId])
}

const Example = () => (
    <RouteNotFoundBoundary fallback={<div>Oh no!</div>}>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/:pageId' component={Template}/>
        </Switch>
    </RouteNotFoundBoundary>
)
```

Not sure if it's a good idea or not, but it might simplify some cases when the code path where you know if the route is valid or not is not the best place to render a 404 page.